# Server side custom control rendering in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Anyone know good behavior for creating server side logic for render custrom control in ASP vNext? I read about tag helpers but i don't know that is the best solution for me. The expected end solution should look similar to:

```
public class CustomControl : Control //here base class with context etc
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        using (var control = _context.Div())
        {
            input.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Content, "Div");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for good documentation that help me implement base `Control` class.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve what WebForms does?

Comment: the tag helpers are the way to go. Check out the "Creating your own tag helpers" section of this blog post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers/. Also see the EnvironmentTagHelper implementation on github as a good start https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/EnvironmentTagHelper.cs

Comment: If you only need a reusable piece of html with some code associated with it you can also look into `ViewComponents` https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html but ViewComponents are more for reusability withing a single application, whereas tag helper are for reusable elements across applications

Comment: @KonstantinDinev in some sense, yes. TagHelpers was my first idea and if i don't find somethig else i will use it

Comment: No @Tseng `ViewComponents` it's not a point

Comment: In main case I want to create logic for generic forms based on my own model. Model will be parsed to html and i need definition of controls that will be mapped.

Comment: You can't achieve exactly the same as in WebForms. You can create control models that render HTML on the page when invoked through razor or a tag helper, but you won't have a mapping between the client and the server that transmits a control state back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Server side custom controls were a solution to a bad ASP.NET design. 
vNEXT is design to not have these same types of problems, and while you could try to reimplement the same bad design issues, you should instead look at using direct HTML rendering and / or JSON, and then let the browser handle the complications with something like HandlebarsJS

also by offloading most of the work to the browser your server will be able to handle a far higher user load.